# Cannot submit form to database

Tags: php, mysql, html, wordpress

I am working with WordPress and I made a form in the admin section. I am trying to submit it to another database (not the default wp one) so I switch databases successfully and do an insert query but I keep getting an error.

This is my code:

```
$selected = mysql_select_db( 'petracms', $serverAccess );
if (!$selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
$query = "INSERT INTO `petra_customers` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Phone`) VALUES ($fName, $lName, $email, $phone)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, 5859475566)' at line 1

This is my input: `(Adam, Page, bofumme@gmail.com, 5859475566)`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: Perhaps it's interpreting the "@" as some form of regex. That'd be my best guess, without knowing much about PHP. Try putting a "\" character in front of the "@" character. Oh, and if that works, consider not using inline variables. Instead, concatenate them. For instance: "values ".$myVariableToInsert.";"

Answer (score 1):

Values in `INSERT` statements need to be enclosed in quotes (except "numbers"):

```sql
INSERT INTO `foo` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES("foo","bar",1)
```

This is how you would (safely) construct a variable for use in query string interpolation (this is frowned upon, though):

```php
$email = sprintf('"%s"', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
$query = "INSERT INTO `foo` (`email`) VALUES($email)";
```

A more elegant way (and far more secure, too), is to use prepared statements (example uses [PDO](http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)):

```php
# Prepare the statement
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `foo` (`email`) VALUES(:email)');

# Substitute placeholders in query and execute it
$sth->execute(array(
    'email' => $_POST['email']
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add quotes `'` to your `INSERT` query. Check out any tutorial on the web on how to do simple inserts, eg here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp